# How do you deal with the fact, that URLs are case sensitive in xPages?

Tags: xpages

How do you deal with the fact, that URLs are case sensitive in xPages even for parameters? For example URL:

```
my_page.xsp?folderid=785478 ... is not the same as ...
my_page.xsp?FOLDERID=785478
```

How to make, for example, a proper check that params contain some key e.g.
param.containsKey("folderid") which desnt work when there is 'FOLDERID' in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use this function:

```
context.getUrlParameter('param_name')
```

then test if it's null or not.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest defining a couple convenience @Functions:

```
var @HasParam = function(parameter) {
 var result:boolean = false;
 for (var eachParam : param.keySet()) {
  if (eachParam.toLowerCase() == parameter.toLowerCase()) {
   result = true;
   break;
  }
 }
 return result;
};

var @GetParam = function(parameter) {
 var result = "";
 if (@HasParam(parameter)) {
  for (var eachParam : param.keySet()) {
   if (eachParam.toLowerCase() == parameter.toLowerCase()) {
    result = param.get(eachParam);
    break;
   }   
  }
 }
 return result;
};
```

Then you can safely query the parameters without caring about case. For bonus points, you could add requestScope caching so that you can skip looping through the keySet if you're examining a parameter that you've previously looked at during the same request.

Comment: Well I think that its more fundamental issue that xpages core should solve rather than each developer with some custom code. Its not about URL params only, even xpage name is case sensitive in URL so
xPage.xsp is not the same as xpage.xsp . But really not sure why such restriction because you cant create both xPage.xsp and xpage.xsp in DDE, its forbidden.

btw. I always thought that web standard is case insensitive URL ... so the "caps lock" should not be the issue.

Comment: well according to the w3c, urls can be case sensitive, however most web servers ignore this requirement.  http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html

Comment: As pipalia mentions, you can use URL substitution and redirection to account for users hand-typing addresses incorrectly and/or giving them easier addresses to remember. But to be perfectly frank, if your users are ever feeling a need to manually type deep links in your application, it's quite likely that the application's layout is  poorly designed.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to decide for one,so either upper or lowercase
other than that i'd suggest something like

```
KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp = null;
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> p in param)
{
if(UPPERCASE(p.Key) == UPPERCASE("folderid"))
{
kvp = p;
break;
}
}
```

syntax isn't correct and idk the uppercase method in c# right now,but you get the point

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is ofcourse the obvious. Be sure that the parameters you are using througout your application are always the same on every url you are generating and know what to expect. A good approach to accomplish this is to create a ssjs function which generates url's for you according to the objects you submit.

In this function you could check which object you are receiving and with the use of keywords and so forth generate the correct url. This way generating twice a url with the same input parameters should always generate the exact same url.

another option would be just to double check with a bit of code like this

```
var key = "yourkey";

if(param.contains(@uppercase(key)) || param.contains(@lowercase(key)){
 // do stuff
}
```

But should not be necesarry if the url you are parsing is generated by your own application

---

**Edit after post of topic starter**

Another option would be to grap the url directly from from the facescontext and to convert it to a string first. When it is a string you can parse the parameters yourself.

Comment: problem here would be that he would have to add every specific key, so if it is not upper and not lowercase,but miXedCase(for whatever reason)

Comment: I know that I have to keep URLs consistent in my app, thats really obvious :-) , the problem I can see here is the URL is more client side thing, user can type/change URL in browser, and I cant influence this ... for example if user has accidently enabled caps lock, the URL is immediately wrong.

Comment: First, make a descision if you *want to* (or *must*) support users typing URL's. If yes, that make your own SSJS function to read parameters. Create a map from the URL parameters and make all parameter names lowercase, leave the values in the original case. Read the parameter from that map.

Comment: Volker i dont agree with that. As Thimo already stated he needs to be sure if he wants to support this kind of behaviour. If this is not realy neccesary then let the user decide if he wants to see an error page or not because of his/her typo ;).

Comment: I added a third option of working with case sensitive parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine server side substitution/redirection to get around the issue that David mentioned. So a substitution rule will redirect incoming patern like this:

http://myhost/mypage/param (/mypage/* => which converts to - /dbpath/mypage.xsp?*) - substitution is tricky so please handle with care.

Also I believe I read somewhere that context.getUrlParameter is not case sensitive - can someone please confirm this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct; the internal implementation uses equalsIgnoreCase in a loop through the available parameters.